# Posting GZipStream to PHP failing to deflate

Tags: php, .net, compression

I am trying to post JSON using GZipStream to PHP but am not sure how to deflate it on the PHP side. Here is the function to compress:

```
public static string Compress( string text) {
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    var compressed = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
    memoryStream.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);
    var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer);
}
```

It is being called like this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
postData = Compress(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incomingData));
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

On the PHP side I am doing this to receive it:

```
<?PHP
    file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
    file_put_contents('test2.txt', gzuncompress('php://input'));
?>
```

In my apache error log I get this:

```
PHP Warning:  gzdecode(): data error in /var/www/html/gzip.php on line 3
```

and in test.txt I get this:

```
0QAAAB+LCAAAAAAABAAdjsEKgzAQRH9lycWLlfbquVLoRWntqelhiYsGZJNuorUU/70htzcPZhj102rAiFrVz4SNiJOWOxwpGa06F+I1OO7dnWQlgQM0myEfrePEvXxB6L1QiNWF4o2CdxxStdTqTBHtHPLMKZs8nvODafNkIg1gJhRMJEBs3MKJkv1MdibwKMHyCCvOC9XQVtBhnKAoSpgtExxL8C7YfOZYabW/dvUHutMCTtEAAAA=
```

I have also tried `gzdecode`, `gzinflate`, what should I do next to get my JSON back so I can process it with PHP?

UPDATE:
I tried doing what Sammitch suggested, but still getting errors. Using this (https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40) to dump all the request info provides the following:

```
POST /gzip.php HTTP/1.1

HTTP headers:
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
Host: mysite.com
Expect: 100-continue

Request body:
0QAAAB+LCAAAAAAABAAdjsEKgzAQRH9lyaUXK/bqWSn0UmntqelhiYsGZJNuorUU/70htzcPZhj102rAiFrVz4StiJMrdzhSMlp1LsRLcNy7O8lKAkdoN0M+WseJe/mC0HuhEMszxRsF7zikaqFVQxHtHPLMKZs8nvODafNkIg1gJhRMJEBs3MKJkv1MdibwKMHyCCvOC9XQlNBhnOBwKGC2TFAV4F2w+UxVarW/dvUHpEHFyNEAAAA=
```

I tried it both with and without the base64.

Comment: Either add a [`base64_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to the PHP side, or drop the encode from your app. I would favor the latter because it adds about 33% to the size of the payload.

Comment: * "it" being the base64 encoding that bloats the size.

Comment: I would love to not add the extra size, but it seemed maybe easier to debug with the base64 since you can't really share the output of a compressed file here. I updated my post a little.